# Supporting multiple private channels with sockjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, chat, sockjs

I'm trying to make an chat application that supports multiple instance of private conversation between two people. ( similar to facebook's messaging system )

I'm trying to use sockjs to do so, but I am having trouble creating a new instance of sockjs connection for every user - user combination.

Are there any tools that could help me with this?

I've tried multiplexing, but it seems to separate the channel instance, but still share the same connection. ( meaning, people on a different 'channel' are still able to receive my message )

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'Rooms' approach of socket.io , this will let you have a dedicated "channel" per user.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join(userID + '_room');
});
```

Another option is to use dedicate chat servers (http://prosody.im/, ejabberd, and many more).